# Python 3.7 Close when import library

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, quandl

I have problem when try to use library (pandas and quandl). Python suddenly close. (i try other library like cv2 don't have problem work successfully)

Thanks
[import quandl(fail), import cv2(success), import pandas(fail)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3sBU.jpg)

Comment: looks like you're using the alpha release of Python 3.7. I would try the main release.

Comment: @PaulH thanks, i will try